# Asphalt over chip seal

Tags: driveway, asphalt

I currently have a drive way that was chip sealed at some point (I'm guessing when the house was built in 2009...we bought in 2020) and it is finally breaking down and developing some pot holes.

The driveway is about 3600 sq ft.

I have a quote to chip seal it again for $6K or for 2" of asphalt for $14K.  Concrete is just out of budget at over $25K.

I'd like to do the asphalt but can it be laid over the current chip seal?

Not sure of what is under the current chip seal. From the one pot hole it looks like several inches of gravel.

Also the entire driveway is one long hill...300 ft or so.

Thank you
Collin

Comment: What does your paving contractor suggest? Living in the Midwest where chip 'n seal is a common thing, especially on rural county roads, it seems that they'll do several rounds of chip 'n seal, then eventually tear up the old asphalt and lay new.

Comment: He said he would just go over the chip seal with the asphalt. If i wanted concrete he would tear it up and then put the concrete down.

Comment: Have you gotten more than one quote? If not, you may well be overpaying. Also, by getting multiple quotes, you'll be getting the input from multiple pros, familiar with your part of the world, on what's going to work best there. If you get 4 pros all saying "pave over", that's probably a safe bet. If the next three say "rip it out & start over", that's a good reason to question the first guy...

Comment: Good advice.  Ive gotten three quotes on concrete, with this guy being the most thorough in explaining what hed do and also spending the most time answering my questions.  His concrete quote was also in line with the other two, a little cheaper by about 1k.  I called three other asphalt companies and none got back to me. For whatever reason, where I live its very hard to get anyone to call you back.